# How to make array of objects from two another arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays.

```
let arr1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
let arr2 = ['dog']
```

How to create another third array from the result?

```
let arr3 = [{dog: true}, {cat: false}, {mouse: false}]
```

I can't find a way how to create keys from these string?

Answer (score 2):

Map the first array, and use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) to generate the keys from the current array item. Generate the value by checking if the 2nd array includes the current key.

```js
const arr1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
const arr2 = ['dog']

const result = arr1.map(key => ({
  [key]: arr2.includes(key)
}))

console.log(result)
```